# Appropriate regression model when variables were measured on different subjects?

Tags: regression, bootstrap, multilevel-analysis

Imagine the following study design: We have propagated $N$ plants. Each plant produces many seeds. From each plant, $M$ of the seeds are used to measure community composition of bacteria living within the seed in a destructive process. An additional $M$ seeds from each plant are allowed to germinate and the root length of the resulting seedling is measured.

So now we have $N \times M$ measurements of bacterial composition and $N \times M$ measurements of root length. We want to fit a regression model to estimate the effect of bacterial composition on root length. But because it is impossible to measure bacterial composition and root length from the same seed, we do not have $N \times M$ pairs of values.

It does not seem ideal to average the measurements from each of the $N$ plants and fit the model because this would ignore the nestedness of the variation. And it does not seem possible to fit a simple multilevel model because we do not have paired measurements *within* plant. My initial idea was to do a bootstrapping kind of method where we would randomly sample one of each of the $M$ replicates for each of the $N$ individuals and fit the regression model. Then repeat that many times to get a bootstrap distribution for each of the regression parameters. That should incorporate the variation among seeds within a parent plant into the uncertainty distribution.

I would like to know if there is a standard or canonical approach to use in this case or if the bootstrap technique is acceptable. Are there any relevant literature references or textbooks that address this issue?

Comment: (+1) Interesting question! I like your proposed plan, though it's possible there are better approaches that I'm unaware of. Do you know how much of the variation in bacterial composition (and root length, for that matter) is within vs. across plants?

Comment: @mkt I am going to ask the scientists about that because I agree with you that it seems important. If for example all the root lengths from one parent plant are about the same for all its offspring, it won't matter as much how we deal with the issue. But if there are really anomalously high or low root lengths for individual seedlings within a parent plant, we are kind of screwed because we will never know, for that particular seedling, if there was anything different about its particular microbiome composition.

Comment: How genetically different are seeds from the same plant? Idk but they should be virtually identical. Given that, why wouldn't a MANOVA-type or hierarchical model with plants as the unit of analysis work?

Answer (score 2):

##### Consider using an RCT experimental structure with a multilevel model for inference

This is quite a fascinating statistical problem.  It bears a significant resemblance to standard causal analysis where we have multiple treatments that leads to counterfactual alternatives that cannot both occur for the same sampling unit (i.e., testing bacterial composition of the seed versus planting the seed).  However, the difference here is that we are not interested in the causal effect of the treatment itself, but rather, we want to know the association between the outcomes of different treatments for sampling units that come from a common group (in this case, seeds from the same plant).  The main complication is that the different treatments lead to an entirely different output variable we are measuring.

Ultimately, I think this can be handled using a standard RCT experimental structure with a multilevel model for statistical inference.  I do not think the counterfactual nature of the output variable precludes a multilevel model which would make an inference about the group-level (i.e., plant level) association between the two possible outputs.  So long as you randomise the seeds between your two treatment alternatives (so that the selected treatment is not associated with any would-be confounding factors) you should be able to form a model that measures this association in an identifiable way.

Here is an example of a basic multilevel model for this purpose.  Let $k$ denote the categorical variable for the plant identity and let $i$ denote the index for each seed in the plant.  We will use the variable $T$ to denote the binary treatment (with $T=0$ for testing bacterial composition and $T=1$ for planting and testing root length) and we will denote the output variable as $Y$.  As an example, we could form a multilevel model over all plants $k$ and seeds $i$ that is something like this:

$$\begin{align}
Y_{k,i} 
&= \beta_{k,0} (1-T_i) + \beta_{k,1} T_i + (\sigma_{k,0} (1-T_i) + \sigma_{k,1} T_i) \varepsilon_i, \\[18pt]
\begin{bmatrix} \beta_{k,0} \\ \beta_{k,1} \end{bmatrix} 
&\sim \text{IID Dist} \bigg( \text{Mean} = \begin{bmatrix} \beta_{0} \\ \beta_{1} \end{bmatrix} , \text{Var} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_{0}^2 & \rho \lambda_{0} \lambda_{1} \\ \rho \lambda_{0} \lambda_{1} & \lambda_{1}^2 \end{bmatrix} \bigg), \\[12pt]
\begin{bmatrix} \log \sigma_{k,0} \\ \log \sigma_{k,1} \end{bmatrix} 
&\sim \text{IID Dist} \bigg( \text{Mean} = \begin{bmatrix} \phi_{0} \\ \phi_{1} \end{bmatrix} , \text{Var} = \begin{bmatrix} \kappa_{0}^2 & \phi \kappa_{0} \kappa_{1} \\ \phi \kappa_{0} \kappa_{1} & \kappa_{1}^2 \end{bmatrix} \bigg). \\[12pt]
\end{align}$$

In this multilevel model the parameters $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$ represent the mean outcome variables for the two treatments and the parameter $\rho$ represents the correlation between the mean outcome variables at the group-level (i.e., for seeds from a single plant).  So long as you have multiple data points across plants, these parameters should be identifiable model parameters, notwithstanding the counterfactual outcome variable.

You could form multivariate model along these lines and then estimate the parameters using either classical or Bayesian methods.  So far as I can see the parameters should be identifiable so it should be possible to estimate the group-level association of the outputs from the two treatments.

Comment: Do you consider classical methods to include Frequentist methods? Or do you mean something like a [classical interpretation of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_interpretations#Philosophy)?

Comment: Yes, frequentist methods.

Answer (score 1):

It may be useful to try and specify your question in terms of the levels of analysis here. As you've noted, there is no way to map seedling-level bacterial composition to seedling-level root length outcomes, so examining within-plan variation in the relationship is impossible with these data.

(You could imagine modifying the experiment to try and get at within-plant variation. For instance, if you could somehow stratify the seeds collected from the same plant in a way that would capture variation in their bacterial composition, then you could look at variation at the level of the stratum nested within each plant. But that's for some other day.)

So, it seems that it's only feasible to examine the relationship between plant-level variation in bacterial composition and plant-level average root length outcomes. If M for each plant is pretty big and if M is equal across all N plants, then it seems like not the worst thing in the world to average the measurements up to the plant level and just do your regression. There will be some measurement error in the predictor because the bacterial composition measurements are sample averages rather than the true plant-specific typical bacterial composition, which is why it would help for M to be big and equal across plants. (If M varies across plants, then the degree of measurement error would also vary from plant to plant, which makes for a big mess.)

If you don't like averaging the data, then the thing to do is conceptualize the problem as being about the *latent* plant-level attributes, and to think of the seedling-level measurements as manifest, noisy measurements of those attributes. From this perspective, you could analyze the data with a multi-level, multi-variate model, treating both the bacterial composition measurements and the root length measurements as distinct outcomes at the seedling level, with seedlings nested within plants. The multivariate random effects in this model could be interpreted to understand how root length covaries with bacterial composition at the plant level. I think Goldstein's 2011 book on multilevel modeling covers this sort of model.

It's also possible to set up models like this in a structural equation framework, where the seedling measurements are indicators for plant-level latent factors, with root length as one factor and bacterial composition as another factor.